# JContainer, JObject, JToken and Linq confusion

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I am having trouble understanding when to use `JContainer`, `JObject`, and `JToken`. I understand from the "standards" that `JObject` is composed of `JProperties` and that `JToken` is the base abstract class for all of the `JToken` types, but I don't understand `JContainer`.

I am using C# and I just bought LinqPad Pro 5.

I have a JSON data source in a file, so I'm deserializing that file's contents successfully using this statement:

```
string json;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"myjsonfile.json"))
{
    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

At that point, I take the JSON string object and deserialize it to a `JObject` (and this might be my mistake--perhaps I need to make `jsonWork` a `JToken` or `JContainer`?):

```
JObject jsonWork = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

In my JSON data (the string represented by JSON), I have three objects--the top-level object look similar to this:

```
{
  "Object1" : { ... },
  "Object2" : { ... },
  "Object3" : { ... }
}
```

Each object is composed of all sorts of tokens (arrays, strings, other objects, etc.), so it is dynamic JSON. (I used ellipses as placeholders rather than muddying up this question wit lots of JSON data.)

I want to process `"Object1"`, `"Object2"`, and `"Object3"` separately using LINQ, however. So, ideally, I would like something like this:

```
// these lines DO NOT work    
var jsonObject1 = jsonWork.Children()["Object1"]
var jsonObject2 = jsonWork.Children()["Object2"]
var jsonObject3 = jsonWork.Children()["Object3"]
```

But the above lines fail.

I used `var` above because I have no idea what object type I should be using: `JContainer`, `JObject`, or `JToken`! Just so you know what I want to do, once the above `jsonObject#` variables are properly assigned, I would like to use LINQ to query the JSON they contain. Here is a very simple example:

```
var query = from p in jsonObject1
   where p.Name == "Name1"
   select p
```

Of course, my LINQ ultimately will filter for JSON arrays, objects, strings, etc., in the `jsonObject` variable. I think once I get going, I can use LinqPad to help me filter the JSON using LINQ.

I discovered that if I use:

```
// this line WORKS 
var jsonObject1 = ((JObject)jsonWork).["Object1"];
```

Then I get an `JObject` type in `jsonObject1`. Is this the correct approach?

It is unclear to me when/why one would use `JContainer` when it seems that `JToken` and `JObject` objects work with LINQ quite well. What is the purpose of `JContainer`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`JContainer` is a base class for JSON elements that have child items. `JObject`, `JArray`, `JProperty` and `JConstructor` all inherit from it.

For example, the following code:

```
(JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("[1, 2, 3]")
```

Would throw an `InvalidCastException` because you can't store an array in an object, but if you cast it to a generic `JContainer`, it would be fine.

If you know you have a JSON object at the top level, you can use:

```
var jsonWork = JObject.Parse(json);
var jsonObject1 = jsonWork["Object1"];
```

Comment: In your first example, also using (JToken)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("[1, 2, 3]") works. I see from other answer that JContainer can hold everything a JToken can, including other JTokens. Is that the only difference? Your second example works, thanks!

Answer (score 422):

You don't really need to worry about `JContainer` in most cases.  It is there to help organize and structure [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) into well-factored code.

The [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) hierarchy looks like this:

```
JToken             - abstract base class     
   JContainer      - abstract base class of JTokens that can contain other JTokens
       JArray      - represents a JSON array (contains an ordered list of JTokens)
       JObject     - represents a JSON object (contains a collection of JProperties)
       JProperty   - represents a JSON property (a name/JToken pair inside a JObject)
   JValue          - represents a primitive JSON value (string, number, boolean, null)
```

So you see, a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) *is* a [`JContainer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer.htm), which *is* a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm).

Here's the basic rule of thumb:

- If you know you have an object (denoted by curly braces `{` and `}` in JSON), use [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)
- If you know you have an array or list (denoted by square brackets `[` and `]`), use [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm)
- If you know you have a primitive value, use [`JValue`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm)
- If you don't know what kind of token you have, or want to be able to handle any of the above in a general way, use [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm).  You can then check its `Type` property to determine what kind of token it is and cast it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Most examples have simple JSON and I've googled "C# Newtonsoft parse JSON" more than once.

Here's a bit of a JSON file I was just asked to parse for a CSV file. The company name value is nested within many arrays / objects so it is semi-complicated in that regard.

```json
{
  "page": {
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 250
  },
  "dataRows": [
    {
      "columnValues": {
        "companyName": [
          {
            "name": "My Awesome Company",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```cs
var jsonFilePath = @"C:\data.json";
var jsonStr = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);

// JObject implementation for getting dataRows JArray - in this case I find it simpler and more readable to use a dynamic cast (below)
//JObject jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonStr);
//var dataRows = (JArray)jsonObj["dataRows"];

var dataRows = ((dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr)).dataRows;

var csvLines = new List<string>();

for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.Count; i++)
{
    var name = dataRows[i]["columnValues"]["companyName"][0]["name"].ToString();

    // dynamic casting implemntation to get name - in this case, using JObject indexing (above) seems easier
    //var name2 = ((dynamic)((dynamic)((dynamic)dataRows[i]).columnValues).companyName[0]).name.ToString();

    csvLines.Add(name);
}

File.WriteAllLines($@"C:\data_{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.csv", csvLines);
```

Comment: While this is useful information on deserializing complex JSON, it doesn't answer the question that was asked. Please reserve answers for content that addresses the question posed by the asker in the question.