# com.google.gson.JsonArray in Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

I am converting some older c# code that uses com.google.gson to a new code base that uses Newtonsoft.

I need to convert a line of code that is using com.google.gson.JsonArray's 
to Newtonsoft's version.

I've googled this a bunch and cannot find a sample that shows the syntax using Netwonsoft.

Old code:
 `new JsonPrimitive((string) value)`

I'm hoping that I will get something like:
 `JObject.Primitive(value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Json.Net, a [`JValue`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm) represents a JSON primitive (string, number, boolean or null) so your code should translate pretty cleanly as `new JValue(value)`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38560188/10263) if you need more information about the relationship between `JValue`, `JObject` and other types of `JTokens`.