# How to add a JObject inside an existing JArray?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My Jobject is as below:

```
JObject sampleObj = "{
      "operator": "AND",
      "rules": [
        {
          "field": "Entity.Country",
          "condition": "=",
          "value": "'USA'"
        },
        {
          "field": "Entity.ShortName",
          "condition": "=",
          "value": "'Adele'"
        }
      ]
    }"
```

How do I add another JObject inside the JArray "rules" in the JSON? like below

```
    JObject Parent  =
          "{
    "operator": "AND",
    "rules": [{
            "field": "Entity.Country",
            "condition": "=",
            "value": "'USA'"
        },
        {
            "field": "Entity.ShortName",
            "condition": "=",
            "value": "'Adele'"
        },
        {
            "operator": "AND",
            "rules": [{
                    "field": "Entity.Country",
                    "condition": "=",
                    "value": "'USA'"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Entity.ShortName",
                    "condition": "=",
                    "value": "'Adele'"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}"
```

I tried:

```
Parent["rules"].Add(sampleObj);
Parent.selectToken("rules").Add(sampleObj);
```

But, intellisense do not allow me do that. Working on 
C# + Newtonsoft.Json libraries:

```
'JToken' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'JToken' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to cast. `((JArray)Parent["rules"]).Add(sampleObj)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the accessor method [`JObject.Item Property (String)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm), used in `Parent["rules"].Add(sampleObj)`, returns a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm), which is the abstract base class for all possible JSON values -- primitive or non-primitive.  As such it has no `Add()` method, because the derived class [`JValue`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm) representing a primitive value has no `Add()` method.

Thus you will need to cast `Parent["rules"]` to its actual type, which is [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm), in order to add an array item:

```
((JArray)Parent["rules"]).Add(sampleObj);
```

If you think it looks cleaner, you can use [`JToken.Value<T>(Object key)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Value__1.htm) instead of an inline cast, which does the same thing:

```
Parent.Value<JArray>("rules").Add(sampleObj);
```

Or, if there's a chance that the `"rules"` array hasn't been created yet:

```
var array = Parent.Value<JArray>("rules") ?? (JArray)(Parent["rules"] = new JArray());
array.Add(sampleObj);
```

Similarly, [`JToken.SelectToken Method (String)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) returns a `JToken` and so casting is also required.

Related:

- *[JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212978/3744182)*.
- *[JContainer, JObject, JToken and Linq confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38560188/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wTppEI).

Comment: Thanks much for sharing those useful links pal. That sure helped. @dbc