# Get Key Name from nested json object

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I am new to C# and JSON and need some help in getting the Key name(s) in a list of a nested JSON object. The keys are dynamic so I won't necessarily know the keys.

sample code I've tried.

```
protected void test()
{
        var mystring = @"{
          ""zone1"": {
            ""sites"": {
              ""site1"": {
                ""to"": ""email1"", 
                ""subject"": ""subjecttxt"", 
                ""link"": ""somesite""
            },
            ""site2"": {
              ""to"": ""email1"", 
              ""subject"": ""subject"",
              ""link"": ""somesite""
            }
          }, 
          ""zone2"": {
            ""to"": ""email1"", 
            ""subject"": ""subject"", 
            ""link"": ""somelink""
          }}";
        var rss = JObject.Parse(mystring);

        foreach (var section in rss)
        {
            Console.Write(section.Key);
            IList<JToken> result = rss["zone1"]["sites"].Children().ToList();
            var zone = section.Key;
            var site = rss[zone]["sites"];
            foreach (var subsite in rss["zone1"]["sites"])
            {
                var subs = subsite.Parent.ToString();
                // some other code
            }
         }
}
```

Looking for a result:

site1,
site2,
...

I can get the children as IList but looking for something similar to "section.Key" as noted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is to get the properties of the sites. Since accessing the `rss["zone1"]["sites"]` returns a `JToken`, you will need to convert that to `JObject` and then use Properties() method to get the data you need.

```
var sites = ((JObject)rss["zone1"]["sites"]).Properties();
```

Then you can simply iterate over the `IEnumerable<Jproperty>` to get the `Name` of the property or whatever else you need from under it.

To get the section.Key for the sites, you can use the following code.

```
foreach(var site in (JObject)rss["zone1"]["sites"]) {
    Console.WriteLine(site.Key);
}
```

**Output:**

```
site1
site2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first call to `JObject.Parse` already does all the work of converting a string into a structured JSON object. The currently-accepted answer redoes some of this work by (1) turning a structured JSON object back into a string, and then (2) re-parsing it with `JObject.Parse`. There is a simpler way.

Instead, you can cast the value stored at `rss["zone1"]["sites"]` into a `JObject`. (The expression `rss["zone1"]["sites"]` has type `JToken`, which is a parent class of `JObject`, but in this case we happen to know that `rss["zone1"]["sites"]` is always JSON object, i.e. a collection of key-value pairs. Therefore, this cast is safe to perform.)

This is what the code might look like:

```
var sites = (JObject) rss["zone1"]["sites"];
foreach (var site in sites)
{
  Console.WriteLine(site.Key);
}
```

Comment: See this answer for an explanation of the class hierarchy of JSON.NET: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38560188/8201661. When you have a variable of type `JToken`, but you know the value you have stored in that value is a `JObject` (or `JArray` or `JProperty`...), it's safe to cast that variable to `JObject` (or `JArray` or `JProperty`...) so you can access the more-specific fields and methods.

Comment: This solution certainly looks cleaner. It amazes me how simple it is but was struggling with it. Not sure how I would accept this without taking away credit from the previous answer - since it answers the question.